# What meaning this haxe error:Normal variables cannot be accessed with 'super', use 'this' instead

Tags: haxe, openfl

I have a haxe code at the below:

```
private function get_parent() : DisplayObjectContainer
{
    return !!(_parent != null) ? _parent : super.parent;
}
```

However, Haxe always reports super.parent with error:Normal variables cannot be accessed with 'super', use 'this' instead

Who can help me? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: You are not including enough information `super` would be used to inherit an overridden member from a base (super) class. You are not showing a minimal example including the base class and the current class’s declaration of `parent`.

Comment: Thank for your reply. When you click "super.", Haxe give a combox where the property parent is available to here, so I think super can access to the property parent. I add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your class is already a DisplayObject, and as such the parent should not have multiple possibilities for where it is defined. Can you simply try `return this.parent;`?

Comment: Okay, I try it, no error happens. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have another question. Haxe supports Function.apply(this, paramArray) that is similar to Javascript? Thanks.

Comment: I think you want: Reflect.callMethod(Main, Reflect.field(Main, "f"), []);
Docs: https://haxe.org/manual/std-reflection.html
The best place to ask simple questions is the (Haxe community forum.)[1] 


  [1]: https://community.haxe.org/